# How do I escape the - character in SQLite FTS3 queries?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, fts3

I'm using Python and SQLAlchemy to query a SQLite FTS3 (full-text) store and I would like to prevent my users from using the - as an operator. How should I escape the - so users can search for a term containing the - (enabled by changing the default tokenizer) instead of it signifying "does not contain the term following the -"?

Answer (score 1):

From elsewhere on the internet it seems it may be possible to surround each search term with double quotes "some-term". Since we do not need the subtraction operation, my solution was to replace hyphens `-` with underscores `_` when populating the search index and when performing searches.

Answer (score 0):

From [this documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) it seems that it is not really possible. Try to replace your `-` with whitespace before searching…